# How to link OmniAuth identification (working) and Google Api Calls

Tags: ruby, google-api, omniauth

After a day trying, testing, googling ... I ask for some help 
I try to use Omniauth and Google Calendar. OmniAuth is working like a charm but I just can't link it with Google API

I think I read almost everything, I still get this error message :

> dailyLimitExceededUnreg: Daily Limit for Unauthenticated Use Exceeded.
>   Continued use requires sign up.

It means that my calls are not properly 'connected' to my auth, which seems to be valid. My tokens are in databases but I this point I would like to login / identify / call and have something else that an error message.

client_id = Google::Auth::ClientId.from_file('.....googleusercontent.com.json')

```
scopes =  ['userinfo.email,calendar']

token_store = Google::Auth::MyTokenStore.new()

authorizer = Google::Auth::WebUserAuthorizer.new(
    client_id,
    scopes,
    token_store,
    'http://localhost:3000'
)

# credentials = Google::Auth::UserAuthorizer.new( .  # Anotheir test
#     client_id,
#     scopes,
#     token_store,
#     'http://localhost:3000'
# )
#
# authorizer = credentials.get_credentials_from_code(
#     GoogleUser.find(session[:user_id]) # I tested token ... notking worked
# )

calendar = Google::Apis::CalendarV3::CalendarService.new
calendar.authorization = authorizer
calendar_id = 'primary'

@result = calendar.list_events(calendar_id,
                               max_results: 10,
                               single_events: true,
                               order_by: 'startTime',
                               time_min: Time.now.iso8601)
```

and my token storage , I don't understand why but never called

```
class MyTokenStore
  class << self
    attr_accessor :default
  end


  def load(_id)
    puts "********** load ************"
    return GoogleUser.find(session[:user_id]).access_token
  end


  def store(_id, _token)
    puts "********** store ************"
    @user.access_token = _token
  end


  def delete(_id)
    puts "********** delete ************"
    @user.access_token = nil
  end
end
```

end
end

Answer (score 0):

For future readers : I took a different technic, after reading an excellent article here : http://gmile.me/simple-google-auth/
I followed it and use signet, it is working like a charm